# Relationship between complexity classes W[1] and NP?

Tags: np, parameterized-complexity

I am trying to understand the connection between *The W-hierarchy* as presented in chapter 13 of [this book](http://parameterized-algorithms.mimuw.edu.pl/parameterized-algorithms.pdf) by Cygan et al. and the notion of the *NP* problems.

Is the existence of an FPT algorithm for a problem in *W[1]* suggests that *P=NP*? Why?

For example, assuming I have an FPT algorithm for the [*k-Clique problem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem). Can I prove the *P=NP*? The algorithm run time will still be exponential. Only now, it will depend on $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Because $k$-CLIQUE is W[1]-hard, your result would imply that FPT = W[1], which by the result of Downey and Fellows [1] implies that the Exponential Time Hypothesis (ETH) is false, i.e., that 3-SAT *can* be solved in $2^{o(n)}$ time. But ETH is stronger than P not equal to NP, so its falsification doesn't settle P = NP (but of course, if true, ETH would imply that P is not equal to NP).

As far as I know, FPT = W[1] is not known to imply anything else regarding the W-hierarchy.

---

[1] Downey, Rodney G., and Michael Fellows. Parameterized complexity. Springer Science & Business Media, 2012.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathrm{FPT}=W[1]$, then we will not directly get an answer to $\mathrm{P}$ vs. $\mathrm{NP}$ (or at least, not that we know). The assumption that $\mathrm{FPT} \neq W[1]$ is a weaker claim than $\mathrm{P}\neq \mathrm{NP}$:

If $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$, then there is polynomial time algorithm for the $W[1]$-complete problem $k$-Clique, so $\mathrm{FPT}= W[1]$. Taking the contrapositive, we get that $\mathrm{FPT}\neq W[1]$ implies $\mathrm{P}\neq \mathrm{NP}$.

Taking a step back, the entire concept of fixed parameter tractability implicitly assumes that there are problems for which we cannot obtain a polynomial time algorithm. By applying this concept to NP-complete problems, we make the assumption that we are unable to prove $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$. While this argument does not rule out a proof of $\mathrm{FPT}=W[1]$ implies $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$, it does not seem natural that a collapse of complexity classes designed to give more fine-grained results when $\mathrm{P}\neq \mathrm{NP}$ would imply $\mathrm{P} = \mathrm{NP}$.